# Modify default widget text color with applied stylesheet of QTreeWidget items

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside, qtstylesheets, qtreewidgetitem

I have a `QTreeWidget` (however this question relates to any kind of widget) in which I have items which, under certain circumstances change their foreground color to red using `item.setForeground(0,QBrush(QColor("red")))`.

Later they can change their foreground color back to black. But the problem is that if the widget has been set some stylesheet which has changed the foreground color to other than black, I am in trouble. My question is how to revert the color of an item to the default color used by the widget for text color given the applied stylesheets?

For example if I apply a dark stylesheet which makes widget background dark and default text color white, first I can see white items, then they change to red and then they become black. But I want them white again. But I do not know how to find that it is white (and not black) color they should change to.

I tried this:

1) if I use `item.setForeground(QtGui.QBrush())` which I hoped would use empty and therefore default brush, I always get black text

2) if I query the text color `treeWidget.palette().text().color()` I always get the same color regardless of the stylesheet

Comment: I am afraid I asked a bit off XY question... My aim was to just reset the foreground color, but my attempts with `setForeground()` let me far away from the correct and simplest solution (suggested by ekhumoro below) to dig into stylesheets etc.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question doesn't really apply to "any kind of widget", because there is no guarantee that setting the foreground colour will always work. To quote from the docs for [QPalette](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpalette.html):

> **Warning**: Some styles do not use the palette for all drawing, for
>   instance, if they make use of native theme engines. This is the case
>   for both the Windows XP, Windows Vista, and the Mac OS X styles.

However, if the question is restricted to model items (such as `QTreeWidgetItem`), you can clear the current settings like this:

```
item.setData(column, QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole, None)
```

On platforms that **do** allow changes via the palette, you could get the default palette like this:

```
palette = QtGui.qApp.style().standardPalette()
```

which should then allow you to restore the original values.

Comment: This `item.setData(...)` seems to solve my problem, unlike `item.setForeground()` which I had been using. Actually I finally found one another way: to override `MyTreeItem.data(column, role)` method to return None for foreground role. But `setData(...)` seems to be more elegant option because it does not need definition of my own item class.